# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopVideo' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have below code for Youtube API player. I defined functions i.e. playVideo, stopVideo etc. But it gives an error of undefined functions.

After a lot of research, I am still unable to figure out this error.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Videos</title>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="player">
  <iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sGPrx9bjgC8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   <br/>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick = "playVid()">Play</a>||
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick = "stopVid()">Stop</a>||
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick = "muteVid()">Mute</a>||

  </div>
</body>
</html>

**script.js**

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
tag.scr = "https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflioRwVn/www-widgetapi.js";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

window.onYouTubeIframeReady = function(){
   player = new YT.Player('player', {
       videoId: 'sGPrx9bjgC8',
       events: {
           'onReady' : onPlayerReady,
       }
   } );
}

function onPlayerReady(event){
    event.target.playVideo();
}

function playVid(){
    player.playVideo();
}

function stopVid(){
    player.stopVideo();
}

function muteVid(){
    player.mute();
}
```

[Here is my erorrs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P5QN.png)

Comment: you could try with function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() { in place of window.onYouTubeIframeReady = function(){

Comment: I have tried that too. But still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.It worked for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Videos</title>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflioRwVn/www-widgetapi.js";
tag.setAttribute('onload','onYouTubeIframeReady()');
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

window.onYouTubeIframeReady = function(){
     player = new YT.Player('player', {
         videoId: 'sGPrx9bjgC8',
         events: {
             'onReady' : onPlayerReady,
         }
     } );
}

function onPlayerReady(event){
    event.target.playVideo();
}

function playVid(){
    player.playVideo();
}

function stopVid(){
    player.stopVideo();
}

function muteVid(){
    player.mute();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="player">
    <iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sGPrx9bjgC8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick = "playVid()">Play</a>||
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick = "stopVid()">Stop</a>||
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick = "muteVid()">Mute</a>||
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay then mark the answer as correct.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your `player` variable is not set to `YT` object as you are expecting.

1. You might be calling the `PlayVid()` function before the `onYouTubeIframeReady` callback happens.
2. Another issue in your code is the fact that you are using the same `id="player"` name for more than one element on your page. Please, rename your `div`'s id to something else.

For example:

```
<div id="player-wrapper">
  <iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" src="..."
```

Comment: I have tried all the ways. But I am still not able to figure out this error.